# How can i display my Magento products in two columns?

Tags: magento

I have this block of code `

```
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div>
<?php echo $this->__("There are no products matching the selection. Please provide a category ID.") ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>

<?php if ($now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo)?>
<table class="c-body-container" style="clear: both; width: 676px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 7px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>                      
<td class="c-2up-unit c-left" style="width: 324px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 7px;">
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="c-block-link"  href=”<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>”>
<img src=”<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(110, 110); ?>” alt=”<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>” />
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ![enter image description here][1]>
<a style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName();?></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php endif ;?>`
```

and i want them to display in two columns how would i achieve this??my output was the image below. but i wanted two display the products in two columns

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as folows:

I have changed the foreach html, please remove  and  outside the foreach.

```
<?php $totCount = $_productCollection->count(); $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php if($i%2==0): ?>
    <tr>
<?php endif; ?>          
        <td class="c-2up-unit c-left" style="width: 324px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 7px;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a class="c-block-link"  href=”<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>”>
                            <img src=”<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(110, 110); ?>” alt=”<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>” />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ![enter image description here][1]>
                        <a style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName();?></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    <?php if($i%2==0 || $i==$totCount): ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

I havent check this, but after replacing you need to tweak a bit to get correct result.

Comment: Already solved it big thanks to you SKV. Just assign 1 to $i and $i%2 ==1

Answer (score 0):

Open the catalog.xml file which can be found in the location below:
/app/design/frontend/package-name/your-theme/layout/catalog.xml

Locate the following line that declares the block for product listing similar to the one below:

Immediately after the code above, add the XML node below:
4

Save the file and clear the contents of your var/cache directory. Reload the catalog page to see the changes